# Lightbox2, wrong count because of additional text link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox2

I'm using [Lightbox2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) in a fairly standard implementation: click on an image in a series (all with `rel="lightbox[gallery]"`) and it opens in the Lighbox with the next/prev arrows pointing to the next and previous image in the series. I also have a text link that points to the first image and opens the gallery (also with `rel="lightbox[gallery]"`).

The problem is that, for some reason, that text link is counting as an image in the series. So when the 6 image gallery loads, it claims there are 7 images (the first counting twice). What's more is that it loads on image 2 of 7, skipping the first one (which is a duplicate anyway).

If I remove that text link, all is well. But, of course, I can't. So what are my options? Can I use javascript to initiate the Lightbox (so the link doesn't count as an image in the gallery)? Anyway, code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox.js"></script>

<!-- THIS IS THE TEXT LINK. NOTE THAT IT IS IDENTICAL TO THE FIRST IMAGE LINK -->
<a href="first.jpg" title="I am image one of three" rel="lightbox[gallery]">View Gallery</a>

<!-- THESE ARE THE GALLERY IMAGES. NOTE THAT THERE ARE 6 OF THEM. WHEN GALLERY LOADS, IT WILL THINK THERE ARE 7 BECAUSE OF THE TEXT LINK ABOVE -->
<a href="first.jpg" title="I am image one of three" rel="lightbox[gallery]"><img src="first_sm.jpg"></a>
<a href="second.jpg" title="I am image two of three" rel="lightbox[gallery]"><img src="second_sm.jpg"></a>
<a href="third.jpg" title="I am image three of three" rel="lightbox[gallery]"><img src="third_sm.jpg"></a>
<a href="fourth.jpg" title="I am image four of three" rel="lightbox[gallery]"><img src="fourth_sm.jpg"></a>
<a href="fifth.jpg" title="I am image five of three" rel="lightbox[gallery]"><img src="fifth_sm.jpg"></a>
<a href="sixth.jpg" title="I am image six of three" rel="lightbox[gallery]"><img src="sixth_sm.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: Can you show your lightbox initializer code?

Comment: Okay. I edited the post to include the link to the script. Is that what you mean? Lightbox doesn't really require any initializer. If the script is running on the page, it just fires off on every `<a>` that has `rel="lightbox"`. Does that help? Or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out! I added an `id` to the first image:

```
<a id="first_img" href="first.jpg" title="I am image one of three" rel="lightbox[gallery]"><img src="first_sm.jpg"></a>
```

Then I change the text link to a `<span>` with an `onClick` like so:

```
<span onclick="$('#first_img').click();">View Gallery</span>
```

I styled the `<span>` to look and behave like a link, and voila!

(*Sometimes all it takes is writing out your question to get to the answer!*)